# call JTree and put in scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, components, jtree

I make a JTree by using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) tutorial.
Now I want to call this class and put it in a ScrollPane.

but when I use this

```
    TreeMainMenu tree = new TreeMainMenu();
    JScrollPane MainMenu = new JScrollPane(tree);
```

it get only the default Tree. I need to understand how to call Components from an other class to use them.

JTree:

```
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class TreeMainMenu extends JTree {


private DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("TOP");


public TreeMainMenu() {

    APNode();
    JTree tree = new JTree(top);



 tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
}


private void APNode() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode category = null;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node1 = null;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node2 = null;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node3 = null;

    category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("top");
    top.add(category);

    node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Node("top-1"));
    category.add(node1);
    node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Node("node1"));
    node1.add(node2);
    node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Node("node2"));
    node1.add(node2);
    node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Node("node3"));
    node1.add(node2);
    node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Node("node4"));
    node1.add(node2);

}

private class Node {
    public String nodeName;

    public Node(String node) {
        nodeName = node;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return nodeName;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TreeMainMenu` class is already `JTree` therefore  you needn't create a new one `JTree tree = new JTree(top);`

You create a new tree with your nodes, but instance of `TreeMainMenu` have default nodes. So you can use `TreeMainMenu extends JPanel` and add your tree(that you create in constructor) to that panel or you need to use instance of `TreeMainMenu` as `JTree` and your constructor can be like next:

```
public TreeMainMenu() {

    APNode();
    setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(top));
    getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
}
```